# Python: Rebining a plotly Histogram in a Dash server

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When zooming into a Histogram in plotly the bin size stays the same.
I would like to rebin, so to change the bin size upon zooming into the Histogram. This is possible see here: https://community.plotly.com/t/jupyter-widget-zoomable-histogram/16849
But the Histogram which I would like to rebin is in a dashboard that I run from Jupyter notebook.
simply implementing this code and then trying to run it in the dashboard doesn't seem to work.

So far I have tried to implement the code into the dashboard. I have tested if the handle_zoom function is called by letting it also change the title. This did not happen. But the code still runs through just without rebinning or changing the title when zooming.
I am now wondering, if this example can be used, when using dash in python or if the same functionality can be reached in any other way?

The first Block in the jupyter notebook generates the graph in the jupyter notebook, in which I can zoom:

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html

# Generate dataset
x = np.random.randn(5000)

# Create figure and get reference to histogram trace
fig = go.FigureWidget(
    [go.Histogram(x=x)],
    go.Layout(
        xaxis={'range': [-4, 4],
               'title': 'x'}))
hist = fig.data[0]

# Install xaxis zoom callback
def handle_zoom(xaxis, xrange):
    filtered_x = x[np.logical_and(xrange[0] <= x, x <= xrange[1])]
    hist.x = filtered_x #here we assign the x,that we have  selected, that are in range as the new x.
fig.layout.xaxis.on_change(handle_zoom, 'range') #here we tell the program that it should use the function, when
#the x-axis is changed.

# Display FigureWidget
fig
```

The second cell then hosts an external Dash board with the same figure. Now it is not possible to zoom anymore:

```py
app = JupyterDash(__name__) # Hier initalisieren wir die app
app.layout = html.Div ([
    html.Div([ # This is the first row.
        dcc.Graph(id = 'first-Graph', figure = fig)
    ]),
])

# Run app 
app.run_server(mode='external') # Let the code run on an external website
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)